# Query DynamoDB using a script in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, aws-cloud9

I have a DynamoDB table. I need to perform write/read/delete operations on this table. This needs to be done using a script. I can think of two approaches:

1. Using AWS Lambda
2. Using AWS Cloud9

Are there any other ways to do this task using the services provided by AWS?

Comment: Why would you want to use Cloud 9 vs writing a script in a supported programming language such as Python script?

Comment: You can do this from any environment that can run an AWS SDK and supported programming language including, but not limited to, Lambda, EC2, ECS, etc. Or use the awscli, available for most platforms.

Answer (score 1):

For  using AWS Lambda , there is a method to integrate your DynamoDB table with a AWS Lambda function. First, you need to:

1.Create a new Lambda function and DynamoDB database that are integrated together

The first thing you will need to do if you have already created the DynamoDB table:

create the function:

```
amplify add function

? Provide a friendly name for your resource to be used as a label for this category in the project: mylambda
? Provide the AWS Lambda function name: mylambda
? Choose the function runtime that you want to use: NodeJS
? Choose the function template that you want to use: Hello World
? Do you want to access other resources created in this project from your Lambda function? Y
? Select the category: storage
? Select the operations you want to permit for testtable: create, read, update, delete
? Do you want to invoke this function on a recurring schedule? N
? Do you want to edit the local lambda function now? N
```

Deploy the function and database:

```
amplify push
```

2. Next you can call DynamoDB table from Lambda in Node.js by:

A.) Create an item in DynamoDB from Lambda

To create an item in DynamoDB you can use the put method:

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const docClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();

const params = {
  TableName : 'your-table-name',
  /* Item properties will depend on your application concerns */
  Item: {
     id: '12345',
     price: 100.00
  }
}

async function createItem(){
  try {
    await docClient.put(params).promise();
  } catch (err) {
    return err;
  }
}

exports.handler = async (event) => {
  try {
    await createItem()
    return { body: 'Successfully created item!' }
  } catch (err) {
    return { error: err }
  }
};
```

Getting an item by primary key in DynamoDB from Lambda:
You can also obtain a primary key from DynamoDB by using the get method. A get request returns a single item given the primary key of that item:

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const docClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();

const params = {
  TableName : 'your-table-name',
  /* Item properties will depend on your application concerns */
  Key: {
    id: '12345'
  }
}

async function getItem(){
  try {
    const data = await docClient.get(params).promise()
    return data
  } catch (err) {
    return err
  }
}

exports.handler = async (event, context) => {
  try {
    const data = await getItem()
    return { body: JSON.stringify(data) }
  } catch (err) {
    return { error: err }
  }
}
```

Scanning a table:
This will  return one or more items and item attributes by accessing every item in a table or a secondary index.

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const docClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();

const params = {
  TableName : 'your-table-name'
}

async function listItems(){
  try {
    const data = await docClient.scan(params).promise()
    return data
  } catch (err) {
    return err
  }
}

exports.handler = async (event, context) => {
  try {
    const data = await listItems()
    return { body: JSON.stringify(data) }
  } catch (err) {
    return { error: err }
  }
}
```

Querying a table:
A query returns one or more items and item attributes by querying items from a table by primary key or secondary index.

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const docClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();

var params = {
  TableName: 'your-table-name',
  IndexName: 'some-index',
  KeyConditionExpression: '#name = :value',
  ExpressionAttributeValues: { ':value': 'shoes' },
  ExpressionAttributeNames: { '#name': 'name' }
}

async function queryItems(){
  try {
    const data = await docClient.query(params).promise()
    return data
  } catch (err) {
    return err
  }
}

exports.handler = async (event, context) => {
  try {
    const data = await queryItems()
    return { body: JSON.stringify(data) }
  } catch (err) {
    return { error: err }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My answer is a quick solution for development purposes and not conducive to a thorough strategy or proper architecture.

If you are working in a cloud9 environment and want to quickly query dynamodb from within that environment, you may find it useful to **create a python script** which you can then quickly and easily run. This will save you having to deploy / configure additional infrastructure.

Python Code:

```
import boto3
from boto3.dynamodb.conditions import Key, Attr

dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb', region_name='ab-cont-1')
table = dynamodb.Table('MyTableName')

response = table.query(
    ProjectionExpression="Col1, Col2",
    KeyConditionExpression=Key('Col1').eq(123)
)

print(response['Items'])
```

If this is saved as **script.py** in the current working directory, from the shell:

```
#pip3 install boto3
python3 script.py
```